# How to initialize iterator over dataset when you pass it to keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to pass an iterator over Tensorflow dataset to Keras, and I get an error that the iterator was not initialized. How should I do it properly?

Here there is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

K = keras.backend

# Input parameters:
batch_size = 2

# Get some data:
num_data_points = 100
images = np.random.normal(size=(num_data_points, 5, 5, 3)).astype(np.float32)
masks = np.random.normal(size=(num_data_points, 5, 5, 3)).astype(np.float32)

# Number of batches:
num_batches = num_data_points // batch_size
if num_batches * batch_size < num_data_points:
    num_batches += 1
    assert num_batches * batch_size > num_data_points
else:
    assert num_batches * batch_size == num_data_points

# Initialize model:
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
K.set_session(session=sess)

with graph.as_default():

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensors=(images, masks))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size).repeat()

    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(
        output_types=dataset.output_types, output_shapes=dataset.output_shapes
    )
    iterator_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset=dataset)
    iterator_images, iterator_masks = iterator.get_next()

    # Import some model:
    complex_model = keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=3,
        kernel_size=(1, 1),
        activation="relu",
        padding="same",
        data_format="channels_last",
    )

    inputs = keras.layers.Input(tensor=iterator_images)
    outputs = complex_model(inputs)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
        loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: K.mean(
            K.binary_crossentropy(target=y_true, output=y_pred)
        ),
        target_tensors=[iterator_masks]
    )

    model.fit(epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=num_batches)
```

It results in the following error:

> FailedPreconditionError: GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.
>        [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,5,5,3], [?,5,5,3]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

In the case of using only Tensorflow, I would have to do something like:

```
sess.run(iterator_init_op)
```

How should I do that using Keras APIs?

Comment: You can get the current session object from the backend using K.get_session() and then run the initializer op?

Comment: I have a direct access to `sess` because I explicitly instantiate it. I am not sure though it would be a proper way to do so.

Comment: I just though Keras could handle the initialization automatically as it is doing for weights...

Comment: since you're anyway using the repeat function with the dataset, you could use the one shot iterator right? That way keras does the initialization itself and you don't need to worry about end of sequence error

Comment: Hmmm indeed it could be a way to go! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know if that works!

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it seems that one shot iterator is what I was looking for. Thank you again for your response!

Comment: Good to know! Youre welcome